# JavaScript version of jQuery's before

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a simple accordion with just javascript.

I need to place an element before another element in the DOM. I know that I can do this with jQuery's insertBefore, but I am unfamiliar with how to do it using just JavaScript.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore

Comment: If you look at the [jquery source for insertBefore](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js), it just calls `this.parentNode.insertBefore( elem, this );`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native APIs have an `.insertBefore` method. You pass it the element you'd like to insert, and the element you want it inserted in front of.

```js
// Create a new textNode, get reference to container
var foo = document.createTextNode("Foo"),
    div = document.getElementById("foo");

// Insert new textNode before container's firstChild
div.insertBefore(foo, div.firstChild);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/rn5pa/

Comment: Does it seem weird to anyone else that you need to call this method on the parentNode? Doesn't `nodeToInsertBefore.insertBefore(nodeToInsert);` feel much better?

Answer (score 2):

Use `insertBefore()`:

```
var el = document.getElementById('elementID'),
    newElement = document.createElement('div');

el.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, el);
```

Reference:

- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [insertBefore](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp) method

Comment: Please consider referring to [real documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) instead of [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). Also, your answer should provide something other than just a link.